# BoxWhiskerChart - how to show Quartile and other values

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, labeling, charts

I have a question in respect of the `BoxWhiskerChart`.

The default functionality of `BoxWhiskerChart` is that you mouse over it and it shows you the tooltips - Max, Quartile III, Median, Quartile I and Min.

Is there a way to extract these data below the chart in a table?
Obviously, I think, I could construct my own `Grid` to do that, but I was wondering whether I could somehow pull the data out of the `BoxWhiskerChart` since it is included within it anyway.

Or, at least, how to show the value for the "Upper Quartile" and "Lower Quartile" with the help of Labeling function?

Answer (score 10):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {2, 30}];

bwc = BoxWhiskerChart[data];
```

You can extract the tooltip labels from `bwc` using `Cases`:

```
tooltips = Cases[bwc, Tooltip[a_, t_] :> t, All]
```

[image]

and use them with `Labeled` as a label for the chart:

```
Labeled[bwc, Row[tooltips , Spacer[10]], Bottom]
```

[image]

Alternatively, re-do the chart showing `tooltips` as ticks using the option `ChartLabels`:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, ChartLabels -> Placed[tooltips[[All, 1]], Axis]]
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Comment: What do variables "a_" and "t_" relate to in the Tooltip[a_,t_], just for my understanding?

Comment: @Jiri, [`Tooltip[expr, label]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html)  _"displays label as a tooltip while the mouse pointer is in the area where expr is displayed. "_.  In the rule `Tooltip[a_,  t_] :> t`, `a_` is a placeholder for the first argument and `t_` is a placeholder for the second argument of an expression of the form `Tooltip[...,...]`, and the rule says, for expressions of that form take the second argument (`t`).  Re patterns like `a_`, `t_` see [tutorial/ Introduction to Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html)

Comment: @kgir, again, thank you very much, will read the tutorial!

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain the quartile values using the Quantile function - linear interpolation (hydrologist method).  See the Details section on the [Quantile page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantile.html).

[image]

```
data = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], 1], 100],
   {\[Mu], {0, 3, 2, 5}}];
BoxWhiskerChart[data]
Quantile[data[[1]], {1/4, 3/4}, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}]
```